# While JSON Parsing i have got this kind of Error?

Tags: objective-c, json, ios4

2011-01-24 09:10:29.809 abc[1333:207] -JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Unrecognised leading character\" UserInfo=0x5693680 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unrecognised leading character}"
)

what is this error means i don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're parsing a string that isn't actually JSON.

Comment: i am printing the response string here so you can guide me.

Comment: array(7) {
  ["uid"]=>
  string(1) "6"
  ["Manufacturer"]=>
  string(20) "Silver Moon Concepts"
  ["Title"]=>
  string(31) "Spinning Ninja Star Belt Buckle"
  ["SmallImage"]=>
  string(60) "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41Rz_SL75_.jpg"
  ["DetailPageURL"]=>
  string(173) "http://www.amazon.com/Spinning-Ninja-Star-Belt-Buckle/dp/B000RWN7KG?SubscriptionId=AKIAIMZHUVZDK6G65F6A&tag=ws&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B000RWN7KG"
  ["UPC"]=>
  string(12) "123456789098"
  ["FormattedPrice"]=>
  string(6) "$29.99"
}
Product added successfully@Spinning Ninja Star Belt Buckle

Comment: can you tell me what should i do for solving this issue.

Comment: That is neither JSON nor anything like it.  You cannot parse it with a JSON parser.